# MERGE and condition on the match

Tags: sql-server

I have a table type that I am sending as a variable in my stored procedure.

```
CREATE TYPE OperationKeysTableType AS TABLE 
(
    [KeysId] [int] NOT NULL,                
    [OperationId] [int] NOT NULL,                
    [IsChecked] [bit] NOT NULL
)
```

And then I want to use this table to do a search, if they match or not, insert or delete but only if it is not checked like so:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.tblOperationKeys AS T
USING (SELECT VT.KeysId, VT.OperationId as OperationId FROM @ValuesTable AS VT) AS S
ON T.KeysId = S.KeysId AND T.OperationId = S.OperationId
WHEN MATCHED AND S.IsChecked = 0 THEN --DELETE
    DELETE 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN--INSERT
    INSERT (KeysId, OperationId) VALUES (S.KeysId, S.OperationId)   
OUTPUT $action AS ChangesMade, inserted.OperationKeysId AS new_OperationKeysId, deleted.OperationKeysId AS old_OperationKeysId;
```

My issue is that SQL tells me IsChecked is invalid. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you still not getting this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't SELECTING IsChecked.

At the line:

```
USING (SELECT VT.KeysId, VT.OperationId as OperationId FROM @ValuesTable AS VT) AS S
```

You need:

```
USING (SELECT VT.KeysId, VT.OperationId as OperationId, VT.IsChecked as IsChecked FROM @ValuesTable AS VT) AS S
```